How do I preload sample data in a SwiftData app with a one to many relationship
I have the following data models where a List has many Bullets. Is there a proper way to preload a dummy data set with a one to many relationship like this?
@Model
class List: Identifiable {

let id: UUID
var color: String
var title: String

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var bullets: [Bullet]?
    
    var height: Int {
        return 80 + (bullets!.count) * 10
    }
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), color: String, title: String, bullets: [Bullet] = []) {
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.title = title
        self.bullets = bullets
    }

}

@Model
class Bullet: Identifiable {
let id: UUID
var text: String
var state: Bool
var list: List?

init(id: UUID = UUID(), text: String, isChecked: Bool = false, list: List) {
    self.id = id
    self.text = text
    self.state = isChecked
    self.list = list
 }

}

I've read documentation and searched through several tutorials but non seem to have any explanation of how to pre load data with a relationship, ensuring the bullets are always associated with a list and vice versa.

Create List, insert into model context, in loop create Bullet, append to List object. I am not sure I understand what the problem is?
